# React Native with Redux : data is loaded, render shows empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a react native app with react-redux , redux-persist and redux-thunk.

in the Component, I'm rendering the data from props, if the data length is less than one, i show an error, no data available.

it's always showing 'no data available' but actually data is in the props. as i check the console logs, ( using redux-logger ) data is available in the props.

if i put `forceUpdate()` at `componentDidMount` doesnt even help.

but if i put the `forceUpdate()` with a timeout it will load the data.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
      this.forceUpdate();
    }, 1000);
```

What could be the problem? Is render happening before data loads from props?
CoursesPage.js

```js
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import Courses from "./components/Courses";
import {Actions as routes} from "react-native-router-flux";
import * as courseActions from "./courses.actions";

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 return {
  user: state.auth.user,
  users: state.auth.users,
  courses: state.courses.courses,
  lectures: state.courses.lectures,
  courseDetails: routes.courseDetails,
  openProfile: routes.profilePage
 }
}

function dispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return bindActionCreators({
  getCourses: courseActions.getCourses
 }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchToProps)(Courses);
```

Courses.js

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  NetInfo,
  Alert,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  Platform,
  RefreshControl
} from 'react-native';
import { Loader, Accordion, I18n, CustomNavBar, CustomAccordion } from "../../common/components";
import styles from "../../common/styles";
let DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
let { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class Courses extends Component {
 static propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    users: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  courseDetails: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  courses: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getCourses: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    openProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired
 };

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      isRefreshing: false
    };
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

 componentWillMount(){
    this._isMounted = true;
    const { users, getCourses } = this.props;
    getCourses(users);
 }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.forceUpdate();
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.forceUpdate();
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.forceUpdate();
    }, 2000);
  }

  async loadData(){
    await this.props.getCourses(this.props.users);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.forceUpdate();
    }, 1000);
  }

  selectRow(courseData) {
    this.props.courseDetails({
      courseData: courseData
    });
  }

  renderData(containerList){

    /*  rendering .... */
  
  }

 render() {
    const {user, users, getCourses, courses, openProfile} = this.props;
    const data = courses[user];
    let containerList = [];
    Object.keys(data).forEach((d)=>{
      let courseList = [];
      Object.keys(data[d].courses).forEach((c)=>{
        courseList.push(data[d].courses[c]);
      });
      containerList.push({
        id: data[d].id,
        title: data[d].title,
        courses: courseList
      });
    });

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{ width: width, height: Platform.OS == "ios" ? 64 : 54}}>
            <CustomNavBar
              width={width}
              height={Platform.OS == "ios" ? 64 : 54}
              title={I18n.t("details_page_book_button")}
              titleSize={18}
              buttonSize={15}
              background={"#00a2dd"}
              color={"#FFF"}
              rightIcon={"ios-person-outline"}
              rightIconSize={30}
              rightAction={()=> { openProfile(); }}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={{ height: Platform.OS == "ios" ? height - 114 : height - 130 }}>
            {!this.state.isLoading ?
              <ScrollView
              refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
                  onRefresh={this.loadData.bind(this)}
                  tintColor="#00a2dd"
                  title=""
                  titleColor="#00a2dd"
                  colors={['#00a2dd', '#00a2dd', '#00a2dd']}
                  progressBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                />
              }
            >
              {this.renderData(containerList)}
            </ScrollView>
            :<ActivityIndicator
            animating={true}
            style={{ paddingTop: Platform.OS == "ios" ? (height - 114)/2 : (height - 130)/2 }}
            color={'#00a2dd'}
            size={'small'}
           />}
          </View>
        </View>
    );
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you access `props` in `ComponentWillMount` lifecycle method? I mean  What is value of props from `redux`?

Comment: @Yaseminçidem I can access the props in component will mount, but not all the data is there. please see the screenshot at question. I've updated the question.

Comment: What is your goal in here 
`const { users, getCourses } = this.props;`
`getCourses(users);`
is your action method `getCourses`?.if it is,if you change code with `this.porps.actions.getCourses` for access to action

Comment: getCourses is an action. see the updated code @Yaseminçidem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont change state so it is seen same data.So I suggest you should change code like following.Also you should immutable js to change state.

**courseActions**:

```
export function getCoursesRequest () {
  return {
    type: "GET_COURSES_REQUEST"
  }
}
export function getCoursesSuccess (json) {
  return {
    type: "GET_COURSES_SUCCESS",
    payload: json
  }
}
export function getCoursesFailure (json) {
  return {
    type: "GET_COURSES_FAILURE",
    payload: json
  }
}
export function getCourses (sessionToken) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getCoursesRequest())
    // store or get a sessionToken
    return appAuthToken.getSessionToken(sessionToken)
      .then((token) => {
        return BackendFactory(token).getCourses()
      })
      .then((json) => {
        dispatch(getCoursesSuccess(json))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(getCoursesFailure(error))
      })
  }
}
```

**coursesInitialState**

```
const {Record} = require("immutable");

var InitialState = Record({
    courses: {}
});
export default InitialState;
```

**reducer**:

```
const InitialState = require("./authInitialState").default;    

const initialState = new InitialState();

export const courseReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (!(state instanceof InitialState)) return initialState.mergeDeep(state);
    switch (action.type) {

        case "GET_COURSES_SUCCESS":
            const {value} = action.payload;
            let nextState = state.setIn(["courses"], value;

            return nextState;
        case "GET_COURSES_FAILURE":
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it.